# C-Style casting in C++ giving weird behavior

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, multiple-inheritance

I always read that C-style casts in C++ were the same as reinterpret_cast. However, I just tested this code in Visual Studio, and it appears that C-style casting is performing the same behavior as static cast. Does anybody know why? This seems like a bug...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Thing1
{
    std::string theString;

public:
    Thing1(const std::string& theString) : theString(theString)
    {
        //
    }

    std::string getTheString()
    {
        return theString;
    }
};

class Thing2
{
    std::string theString;

public:
    Thing2(const std::string& theString) : theString(theString)
    {
        //
    }

    std::string getTheString()
    {
        return theString;
    }
};

class Thing3 : public Thing1, public Thing2
{
public:
    Thing3(const std::string& theString1, const std::string& theString2) : Thing1(theString1), Thing2(theString2)
    {
        //
    }
};

int main()
{
    Thing3* thing3 = new Thing3("string1", "string2");
    uintptr_t t3ptr = (uintptr_t)thing3;
    uintptr_t t1ptr = (uintptr_t)((Thing1*)thing3);
    uintptr_t t2ptr = (uintptr_t)((Thing2*)thing3);
    std::cout << t1ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << t2ptr << std::endl;
    std::cout << t3ptr << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives the output:

```
17563752
17563780
17563752
```

Comment: A C-style cast in not necessarily the same as a reinterpret_cast. In C++ a C-style cast will only equate to a reinterpret_cast or a const_cast if a static_cast won't do. I hope I'm not over-simplifying things, but I believe that is the gist of the matter.

Comment: *"I always read that C-style casts in C++ were the same as reinterpret_cast."* - Either you don't remember correctly, or you were particularly unlucky with your choice of reading material.

Comment: Prefer to use the C++ casts *always*. They more explicitly say what you want to do *and* they are easier to search for in source code. Of course, the *very best* is to design the code so no (or very few) casts are ever needed.

Answer (score 8):

C-Style casting isn't the same as reinterpret_cast.

A summary of the cast can be found here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

with the following order:

> a) const_cast(expression);
>
> b) static_cast(expression), with extensions: pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to member to pointer to member of unambigous non-virtual base;
>
> c) static_cast (with extensions) followed by const_cast;
>
> d) reinterpret_cast(expression);
>
> e) reinterpret_cast followed by const_cast.

Comment: @Finke: Obviously, the order was set by the standards committee. The order is listed in section [cast.expr], paragraph 4. C describes cast behavior with type conversion as well.

Comment: @Finke: Says the person who assumed their compiler had a bug because they couldn't be bothered to read any documentation. This behavior is much better than always `reinterpret_cast`ing, and is closer to how casts work in C anyway. Things like `(int)5.5` wouldn't even work if C-style casts were just short-hand for `reinterpret_cast`, and if we pretend that `reinterpret_cast` did just bit-wise type-punning on demand the result of that expression would be useless almost all of the time.

Comment: @Finke: This is documented behavior (and hasn't changed ever). I suppose it's less dumb than using a language feature without bothering to understand what it does.